# Tengo un problema al instalar mi base de datos oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Al momento de seguir todos los pasos de instalación de la base de datos me sale esta advertencia en la cual no tengo el listener activado o el servicio de la bd no esta registrado con el. Es la segunda vez que lo instalo y me sale el mismo problema. ¿Alguna solución ?

Aquí les dejo el link de una imagen que es la advertencia que me sale:
[image: Error]

Comment: El mensaje de error es bastante claro. Indica que revises el log, sin embargo tu pregunta no menciona cuál ha sido el resultado de esa revisión, que es crítica para poder diagnosticar si hay algún problema, cuál es y entonces, evaluar posibles soluciones.

Comment: Si pero al momento de revisar el log solo me sale un block de notas largisimo , volvi a realizar la instalacion y me sale el mismo error , hasta intente con una maquina virtual y me sale el mismo error

Comment: Bien, bienvenido a la lectura de logs. Yo comenzaría buscnado la palabra _error_, a ver a donde me lleva.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías verificar que el listener efectivamente esté activo tal como te indica el mensaje de advertencia.

En la consola ejecuta primero:

```
lsnrctl status
```

Y si no está ejecutando lo arrancas con:

```
lsnrctl start
```

Comment: Si , lo intente pero igual nada :(

Comment: Apaga los **firewalls** que tengas habilitado, puede ser que esté rechazando las conexiones por ese puerto.